# Reopening QGIS project from PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am opening a QGIS project using the following snippet:

```
new_project = False
if not os.path.exists(self.qgis_project_path):
    prj_template_path = os.path.join(self.qgis_template_path, 'project.qgs')
    shutil.copy(prj_template_path, self.qgis_project_path)
    new_project = True    #load default layers because the user is opening a particular project for the first time

QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo(self.qgis_project_path))
if new_project:
    for layername in self._settings['vector_layers']:
        uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
        uri.setConnection(self._settings['db_host'], self._settings['db_port'], self._settings['db_dbase'], self._settings['db_user'], self._settings['db_pass'])
        uri.setDataSource('p_{}'.format(self._project[2].replace('-', '_')), layername, 'geom', '')

        lyr = self._iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(), layername, 'postgres')
        if not lyr.isValid():
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage(u'Failed to open the layer: {}'.format(layername), 'Skytek')
        styleload = lyr.loadNamedStyle(os.path.join(self.style_path, '{}.qml'.format(layername)))
        if not styleload[1]:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage(u'Error loading style: {}'.format(layername), 'Skytek')

    for raster in self._settings['raster_layers']:
        pass

    self._iface.mapCanvas().setDestinationCrs(self._local) #qgis3: QgsProject.instance().setCrs(self._local)
    self._iface.mapCanvas().setMapUnits(QGis.Meters) #qgis3: QgsProject.instance().setDistanceUnits(QgsUnitTypes.Meters)
    QgsProject.instance().setDirty(True)
    QgsProject.instance().write(QFileInfo(self.qgis_project_path))
```

I don't understand why every SECOND time I call this, the loaded project shows no layers in the legend. The project file is copied to the user folder only the first time, also the layers are created only the first time. The only line that is called subsequently is:

```
QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo(self.qgis_project_path))
```

And like I said, layers are added to the legend only every second time the project is read. I noticed when I reopen an existing project file in QGIS with "Project->Open project" it works as expected.

Comment: What happens if you add `QgsProject.instance().clear()` before `QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo(self.qgis_project_path))`?